# How to add data to firebase using for loop javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, firebase

I am wondering whether its possible to add data  to firebase using a for loop because that data I am working with is more or less the same but the number increments by 1. Currently what I am doing is;

```
var usersRef = ref.child("users");
usersRef.set({
  Person1: {
    name: "person1",
    surname: "person1"
  },
  Person2: {
    name: "person2",
    surname: "person2"
  },
  Person3: {
    name: "person3",
    surname: "person3"
  },
  .........
  .........
  Person28: {
    name: "person28",
    surname: "person28"
  }
});
```

What I would instead want to do is:

```
    var ref = new Firebase("https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/web/saving-data/fireblog");
    var usersRef = ref.child("users");
 for (var i = 0; i <= 28; ++i) {
    usersRef.set({
    Person+i: {
    name: "person" + i,
    surname: "person" + i
    }
   });
}
```

Is it possible to something like this? any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
var person = {};

for (var i = 1; i <= 28; ++i) {
    person[ "Person" + i ] = { "name": "person" + i, surname: "person" + i };
}

var ref = new Firebase("https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/web/saving-data/fireblog");
var usersRef = ref.child("users");
usersRef.set( person );
```

NB: index should start at 1

Comment: Thanks @llya I will try this now and let you know how I get along, quick question does 'var usersRef = ref.child("users");' have  to be inside or outisde for loop?

Comment: @Henry sorry, I didn't  pay attention to the way the object was constructed (only to the prop. set the syntax), I've fixed the code.

Comment: Hi, this only seem to take the last number of the loop (28) and therefore overwriting previous data.

Comment: It should work, but there's a typo (`"name": "person" + 1` instead of `"name": "person" + i`)

Comment: @Henry I've fixed the typo and tested, it's working for me.

Comment: Hi, now it doesn't seem to reconigse the + sign ("person" + i) it says Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not but I don't recommend newing up `Firebase` on each iteration unless the docs explicitly specify to do so. And the same goes for the `child` getter. I would move them to outside the loop like so:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/web/saving-data/fireblog");
var usersRef = ref.child("users");
for (var i = 0; i <= 28; ++i) {
    var persons = {};
    persons['Person'+i] = {
        name: "person" + i,
        surname: "person" + i
    }
}
usersRef.set(persons);
```

The bracket notation can be used for getting/setting properties programmatically as well as using keys that are invalid JavaScript.

Comment: but how can I increment each record by 1 using the loop, when I use 'Person+i' it does not work.

Comment: Sorry, missed the point of the question entirely. See the update.

Comment: Hi, this only seem to take the last number of the loop (28) and therefore overwriting previous data.

Comment: @user2687646 you should declare `var persons = {}` *outside* of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your current approach (even if you fix the syntax errors), each new user that you add replaces the previous user(s), since you're calling `usersRef.set()`. If you use [`update()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/update.html) instead of set, it will not overwrite the existing data.

But this seems simpler to me:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://yours.firebaseio.com/");
var usersRef = ref.child("users");
for (var i = 0; i <= 28; ++i) {
    usersRef.child("Person"+i).set({
        name: "person" + i,
        surname: "person" + i
    });
}
```